# RSelenium fails when run by cron under Linux - why?

Tags: r, linux, selenium, cron, phantomjs

I wrote a robot in R to scrape data from a web server. The robot is written in R using RSelenium. I wrote two versions, one with standalone selenium using chrome, the other one using directly phantomjs. Both versions work perfectly well on a Linux server (OpenSuSE) when I start them manually. However, both fail on the server when I start them using **cron**. In the latter case, I get an error like this when I try to create a driver:

> Selenium server signals port = 4567 is already in use.

The port is ok and listening as expected. And this is happening only when I start the script via cron.

Can you possibly hint me what's wrong and how can I solve it? Many thanks.

I tried other ports and a lot of R stuff. I guess the problem is somewhere in cron-R-Rselenium interactions. (The cron works ok on the server with some of my other simpler python scripts that **scrape** static pages.)

This is minimal example with phantomjs.

```
library(RSelenium)
system("./phantomjs --webdriver 4567", wait = FALSE)
Sys.sleep(10)
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "phantomjs", port = 4567L)
remDr <- driver$client
```

It fails on the line `driver <- rsDriver(browser = "phantomjs", port = 4567L)` with the following error message:

> Error in wdman::selenium(port = port, verbose = verbose, version = version,  :
> Selenium server signals port = 4567 is already in use.
> Calls: source ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> rsDriver ->

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close prior connections with one of these:

`remDr$close()`

`remDr$server$stop()`

Comment: I have no previous connections. The script fails when the driver is created, i.e. remDr is not even created.

Comment: What happens when you try a different port, e.g., 8888?

Comment: Also, what happens after you restart r (Session -> Restart R in Rstudio)?

Comment: I tried different ports and also dynamic port selection. It's not the problem.

Comment: Restarting R in RStudio is useless -- it works in RStudio and RScript when started manually. The problem appears when I ask cron to start it.

Comment: I'm probably not going to be much help, but I wonder if the R version (and potentially R-Selenium version) are different when run in RStudio and via Cron. Is `R.version` identical when run both ways?